# How to Raster Layer checked status change?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers

I make plugin with use QListWidget.
Items of QListWidget is Raster Layer name.
When selected items, same name layer checked status changing.

current my code is

```
items = self.dlg.listWidget.selectedItems()
 layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
 for name,layer in layers.iteritems():
  for item in list(items):
   if unicode(layer.name()) == item.text():
    utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
    utils.iface.mapCanvas().setCurrentLayer(layer)
```

but it is not apply.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to turn a raster or vector layer on, you have to make it visible, using

```
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```

Try this from the Python Console

```
name = "myrastername" 
layerlist = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(name)
layer = layerlist[0]
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
print qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
qgis.utils.iface.legendInterface().setLayerVisible(layer, True)
```